# Access: selecting multiple values in a multiselect listbox based on a previous selected value

Tags: ms-access, listbox, multi-select

Sorry if this is a question which is ask many times, but im new to access and have no idea how this matter is called.

In Access I have 3 tables. The first one is Projects
Table Projects has many columns, one of them is Project_Name.

Second table is WBS
Table WBS has also many columns, one of them is WBS_Name and other is Project (which is a dropdown based on Project_Name from table 1).

Sample:
[WBS table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZfmw.png)

The third is Orders, here is where im stuck.
Table Orders has a column called Order_Name, also in this table I have a column called Project (which is also based on Project_Name from table 1. The last column (WBS_Product) is a multiselect listbox with values from WBS_Name from table 2.

[Order table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPDeM.png)

Now in this third table I want to see in the WBS_Product row only the values available for selection based on the Project selected in the second column.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately, inlcuding any sample code, data and errors receiving:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have created some sample data, and posted images. I have no code or errors.

Answer (score 0):

You REALLY should be using forms if you want to customize your data entry like this. Because you're entering data directly into the tables, I don't believe this is possible.